# Hover over div to expose hidden div - Keep active past parent height

Tags: css, hover, mouseover, opacity

I am looking to achieve something simple but getting hung up on it. Here is a rough copy of what I am looking to do: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGZaPr

My Sass for the col-4 parent:

```
      .col-4 {
          background: $primary-color;
          color: $heading-two;
          font-family: $secondary-font;
          text-align: center;
          height: 201px;
          padding: rem-calc(32px 0);
          overflow: visible;
}
```

more-info content before the intro-content:

```
  .more-info {
  @media #{$xlarge-breakpoint} {
      width: calc-percent(70px, $site-width);
  }
    position:absolute;
    width: calc-percent(123px, $site-width);
    height: 201px;
    background: $base-color;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9999;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: $primary-font;
    padding: rem-calc(10px);
    color: $primary-color;
    text-align: left;
    @include transition(bottom, 0.3s, ease-in-out);
    line-height: 1.3;
    @media #{$medium-breakpoint} {
        width: 22.115%;
    }
    &:active {
        display: block;
    }
    &:hover {
        display: block;
    }
    a {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: $secondary-font;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: $primary-color;
      &:hover {
          color: $heading-two;
      }
    }
  } // .more-info
```

My Sass for the hover looks like:

```
  .intro-content {
      //height: 100%;
      &:hover + .more-info {
          opacity: 1.0;
          display: block;
          visibility: visible;
          position: relative;
          z-index: 100000;
      }
  }
```

I want to hover over .intro-content to show the content in .more-info. I would like to be able to keep the more-info div open until I take my cursor out of it so that anyone can click on the link in the box / highlight any text.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: in your HTML there is link color with same bg of the page. why you are using it ?

Comment: @krish, I just quickly swapped out sass variables with colors without really matching up just for the demo. Simple mistake is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use some javascript for that. Something like this..

I edited some of your CSS. just copy and paste the js script into your code and it should start working. Also i edited your CSS and gave you a compile version of it. The Scss version of it can be found [here](http://codepen.io/Justthingsido/pen/OMXqXJ)

**EDIT**

After Examining your website, i found that your `wrapper` class has overflow set as hidden, which is preventing your popup from appearing in full.

The only thing i could find to fix it was to disable it. After disabling it you can see the whole box of `more-info`. (or set it to visible)

```
.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 940px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

also that this to your  more-info hover section.

```
#services-menu .col-4 .more-info:hover {
display: block;
position: relative; /*NEW */
}
```

The position relative will prevent the popup box from overflowing.

Next thing is your media query.

you have set it for a width based on the view port of the webpage. It shouldn't be like that.. 
You should set it to `width: 100%` of col-4 which then could be based on the viewport. That way `more-info` popup is always the same width as `col-4`.

so do this

```
#services-menu .col-4 .more-info {
    display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%; /*instead of the 13.08511% you have as default. */
height: 201px;
background: #ffffff;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 999;
-moz-transition: bottom, 0.3s, ease-in-out;
-o-transition: bottom, 0.3s, ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: bottom, 0.3s, ease-in-out;
transition: bottom, 0.3s, ease-in-out;
line-height: 1.3;
}
```

i don't think you need a media query for that so delete this from you css.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){
  #services-menu .col-4 .more-info {
  width: 8.51064%;
  }
}
```

Once you do that. everything will work just fine.

**END OF EDIT**

---

```js
$("div.intro-content").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find("div.more-info").stop().animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find("div.more-info").stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 200);
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 940px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#services-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 272px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 83px;
  z-index: 5;
}
#services-menu #services {
  padding: 25px 0;
}
#services-menu .col-4 {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 201px;
  padding: 32px 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
#services-menu .col-4 .intro-content:hover + .more-info {
  opacity: 1.0;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 100000;
}
#services-menu .col-4 .more-info {
  /* position:absolute;
  width: 123px;
  height: 201px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.3;
          top: -27px;
          left: 41%; */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 123px;
  height: 201px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 130px;
  left: 44%;
}
#services-menu .col-4 .more-info:active {
  display: block;
}
#services-menu .col-4 .more-info:hover {
  display: block;
}
#services-menu .col-4 .more-info a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
#services-menu .col-4 .more-info a:hover {
  color: red;
}
#services-menu .col-4 img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}
#services-menu .col-4 a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#services-menu .col-4 a span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id="services-menu">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="services">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="intro-content">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/156x96">
          <a href="#">Service Name</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.intro-content -->
        <div class="more-info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt eros quis odio porttitor rhoncus. Ut condim</p>
          <p><a href="#">Start Here</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.more-info -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-4 -->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="intro-content">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/156x96">
          <a href="#">Service Name</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.intro-content -->
        <div class="more-info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt eros quis odio porttitor rhoncus. Ut condim</p>
          <p><a href="#">Start Here</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.more-info -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-4 -->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="intro-content">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/156x96">
          <a href="#">Service Name</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.intro-content -->
        <div class="more-info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt eros quis odio porttitor rhoncus. Ut condim</p>
          <p><a href="#">Start Here</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.more-info -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-4 -->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="intro-content">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/156x96">
          <a href="#">Service Name</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.intro-content -->
        <div class="more-info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt eros quis odio porttitor rhoncus. Ut condim</p>
          <p><a href="#">Start Here</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.more-info -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-4 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#services -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.wrapper -->
</section>
<!--/ #services-menu -->
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Seems like its almost there. Its strange, if I actually hover over the intro-content div the more-info block shows, but only like a 20px wide sliver of it. If I am in the DOM editor and right click on .intro-content and choose :hover the entire more-info box now shows up. Any thoughts? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Do you have have a link that you can share so that i can look at your website and see the code.. what do you mean by `the entire more-info box shows up`. if you mean that you want to be able to scroll inside it then i guess you could give it a height or something. but i would need to look at the code to be able to understand what you are describing.

Comment: @Danny Done. Please review my answer below edit. you will find the instructions to make the necessary changes

Comment: thank you for the time and the very detailed/informative response.